# Woocommerce Cart - Sort by Category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need help. I want to sort prodyct in my cart page by category like this:

Category1

- Product1
- Product2
- Product3

Category2

- Product1
- Product2
- Product3

Category3

- Product1
- Product2
- Product3

I found this code but it is working strange. For some products it is sorting OK, but for other - no. Could you help me?

````
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', function() {

    global $woocommerce;
    $products_in_cart = array();
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($item['data']->id, 'product_cat' );
        $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $terms[0]->name;
    }

    ksort( $products_in_cart );

    $cart_contents = array();
    foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $product_title ) {
        $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];
    }
    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;

}, 100 );```
````

Comment: I think you are sorting `$products_in_cart` array by key `ksort` but the key is not category name but cart key, you should be sorting by value `asort`

Comment: Thanks. But now really some products are not adding to the cart. Other is OK

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set new cart session and you can also utilize `$cart` property passed into action:

( Although I have not tested this idea please try )

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', function($cart) {

   $products_in_cart = array();

   foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ) {
       $terms = wp_get_post_terms($item['data']->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
       $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $terms[0]->name;
   }

   asort( $products_in_cart );

   $cart_contents = array();
   foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $product_title ) {
       $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = $cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];
   }

   $cart->set_cart_contents($cart_contents);
   $cart->set_session();

}, 100, 1 );
```

Comment: Now when i add any product my cart is empty.

Comment: fixed now, should add cart item

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great!

Comment: if the solution works please mark the answer as solved, this helps other people to know there is a solution, thank you very much for your kindness